# Stop autoupdate of IMPORTRANGE

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I have two Sheets connected to each other by IMPORTRANGE: Spreadsheet `A` has a list of names which I have to keep on updating every time a new person subscribes to my company. Other columns have their subscription fee, email addresses etc. 
Spreadsheet `B` has separate sheets/pages for each month where the names of people get automatically updated as I input names in Spreadsheet `A` since I'm using the IMPORTRANGE function.

So suppose I have 50 names in Sheet `A`. For the month of March, two new people subscribe to my company and I add their names in Sheet `A`. I would now want to have 52 names in both sheets `A` and `B`. For April, I'll duplicate the March sheet on Spreadsheet `B` and want the names to get updated in the same way as I input names in Spreadsheet 1. But the issue here is, since both March and April are connected to Spreadsheet `A` by the IMPORTRANGE, March will also start having the names I add for the month of April.

How can I stop the sheet of each month in Spreadsheet `B` from being autoupdated with Spreadsheet `A` at the end of each month?

Please note that I can't be using the Copy+Paste range function since I also need some other columns of Sheet `A` to get updated in Sheet `B`.

Comment: Can you use query( importrange () , "select * where ...") to only return the items prior to a given date?

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do direct, but you can definitely do in parts.
Create a new sheet, only to import the range from other table, but import the range and the Month the person started working.

So your new sheet will look like:

  `A    |   B
 Name  | Month
 Joan  | January
 Lia   | January
 Lucas | March`

Listing every single employee.

Now you do a `=QUERY('Sheet2'!$B3:C8, "select B where (C = 'January')")` in the place you were doing your `IMPORTRANGE`. It will give you as output:

`A
 Name
 Joan
 Lia`

Hope it solves your problem.